# 'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a definition for 'FromARgb'

Tags: c#, system.drawing, system.drawing.color

I have added System.Drawing as a reference, yet this code seems to fail on the line where I declare the new color

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace BitmapParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color a = Color.FromARgb(0, 255, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

So what is going on here? I looked up System.Drawing.Color and it does have a 3-int constructor
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx

Comment: c# is case sensitive.  Lower case "r"

Comment: I have the following two very useful pieces of information for you: 1. FromArgb() is ***not*** a constructor.  2. computers tend to be very picky when it comes to capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try spelling it correctly? This works fine for me:

```
var clr = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 255);
```